# Using a loop to reduce code and removing images with tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

For each winning item i would like to display its corresponding picture on the GUI. At the moment i am writing a bunch of code shown in the if statements to achieve this. I am sure i can use some sort of a loop to reduce the amount of code but unsure at this point how i can achieve this.

I am also having issues with removing the image after each non-winning roll. My current attempt at solving this is shown in the code provided within the else statement at the bottom.

```
chance_of_drop = random.randint(1,100)
if chance >= chance_of_drop:
    winner = np.random.choice(Items, p=probabilities)
    drop['text'] = "You've recieved a drop: " + winner

    if winner == Items[0]:
        Loot_IMG = PhotoImage(file=Images[0])
        reward_img = Label(GUI, image = Loot_IMG, background = bg_color)
        reward_img.Loot_IMG = Loot_IMG #
        reward_img.grid(row = 3, column=1, sticky = N)
    elif winner == Items[1]:
        Loot_IMG = PhotoImage(file=Images[1])
        reward_img = Label(GUI, image = Loot_IMG, background = bg_color)
        reward_img.Loot_IMG = Loot_IMG #
        reward_img.grid(row = 3, column=1, sticky = N)
    elif winner == Items[2]:
        Loot_IMG = PhotoImage(file=Images[2])
        reward_img = Label(GUI, image = Loot_IMG, background = bg_color)
        reward_img.Loot_IMG = Loot_IMG #
        reward_img.grid(row = 3, column=1, sticky = N)
   # AND SO ON.....


#print("You've recieved a drop:", winner)

else:
    luck['text'] = "You are unlucky"

    #REMOVING IMAGE DOES NOT WORK
    Loot_IMG = PhotoImage(file="")
    reward_img = Label(GUI, image = Loot_IMG, background = bg_color)
    reward_img.Loot_IMG = Loot_IMG #
    reward_img.grid(row = 3, column=1, sticky = N)
```

ALSO i will provide both of the lists i have constructed further up within the function:

```
    Images = ["loot/Dexterous_prayer_scroll.png", "loot/Arcane_prayer_scroll.png",
      "loot/Twisted_buckler.png", "loot/Dragon_hunter_crossbow.png",
      "loot/Dinh's_bulwark.png", "loot/Ancestral_hat.png", "loot/Ancestral_robe_top.png",
      "loot/Ancestral_robe_bottom.png", "loot/Dragon_claws.png", "loot/Elder_maul.png",
      "loot/Kodai_insignia.png", "loot/Twisted_bow.png"]


# indivdual drop rates
Items = ["Dexterous prayer scroll", "Arcane prayer scroll",
         "Twisted buckler", "Dragon hunter crossbow",
         "Dinh's bulwark", "Ancestral hat", "Ancestral robe top",
         "Ancestral robe bottom", "Dragon claws",
         "Elder maul", "Kodai insignia", "Twisted bow"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can factor out the duplicated code by using the built-in [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function and something along these lines:

```
if chance >= chance_of_drop:
    winner = np.random.choice(Items, p=probabilities)
    drop['text'] = "You've recieved a drop: " + winner

    for item, image in zip(Items, Images):
        if winner == item:
            Loot_IMG = PhotoImage(file=image)
            reward_img = Label(GUI, image=Loot_IMG, background=bg_color)
            reward_img.Loot_IMG = Loot_IMG #
            reward_img.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=N)
            break
else:
    try:
        reward_img.destroy()  # Remove any existing Label.
    except NameError:
        pass  # Doesn't exist, ignore.
```

Also note that the tkinter `PhotoImage` class only supports images in `.gif`, `.pgm`, or `.ppm` format. To load `.png` images you will need to use the Python Imaging Library (PIL) submodule's [ImageTk.PhotoImage](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageTk.html#PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage) class instead.

**Update to note**:

Tk 8.6 [added built-in support for the `.png`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#images) image file format, so you may not need to use PIL.

Comment: Thanks! Any ideas on how i can remove the images lets say when a button is pressed? Also the images seem to be stacking on top of each other after every roll. Unsure if i have to remove the image at the start of the function aswell

Comment: Yes, try `reward_img.destroy()` (assuming `reward_img` was previously defined).

Comment: Okay, that didnt work. reward_img is defined after the function - should i change the layout so that the function is underneath my tkinter code? UnboundLocalError: local variable 'reward_img' referenced before assignment

Comment: Maybe. There isn't enough information in your question for me answer definitely, but however you do it, you'll need to keep track of the current `reward_img` `Label` widget if you want to delete it at some point. Suggest you see accepted answer to question [Best way to structure a tkinter application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466561/best-way-to-structure-a-tkinter-application).

Comment: The loop solved my first issue, still trying to solve the image deleting issue. Marked as solved - thanks